# Symfony 4 сервисы

Tags: php, symfony

Есть файл сервисов:

```
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Commands,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    /** **/

    app.current_user_factory:
      class: App\Security\Authentication\CurrentUserFactory
      arguments: ['@security.token_storage']

    app.current_user:
      class: App\Entity\User
      factory: ['@app.current_user_factory', getUser]

imports:
    - { resource: 'handlers.yml' }
    - { resource: 'repos.yml' }
    - { resource: 'controllers.yml' }
```

По непонятным мне причинам, **app.current_user_factor** не загружается, то есть и как следствие, объект **app.current_user** получается пустой. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

опытным путем удалось выяснить, что в 4й Симфони, требуется новый синтаксис для сервисов и в том числе, указания фабрик:

```
App\Security\Authentication\CurrentUserFactory:
  arguments: ['@security.token_storage']

App\Entity\User:
  factory: 'App\Security\Authentication\CurrentUserFactory:getUser'
```